# Python output encoding

Tags: python, encoding

Code is presented below.
Runs with python 2 in Debian 9.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import requests
import bs4

# repairing invalid HTML
s = requests.get('http://vstup.info/2017/i2017i483.html')
tmp = s.text.replace("</td></tr></td></tr><tr><td>", "</td></tr><tr><td>")

bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(tmp, "html.parser")

content = bs.find("div", {"id": "okrArea"}).find("table", {"id": "about"}).findAll("tr")

typ = content[1].findAll("td")[1].get_text() #ZVO type

print typ
print [typ]
```

It outputs this:

```
Ð¢ÐµÑ
Ð½ÑÐºÑÐ¼ (ÑÑÐ¸Ð»Ð¸ÑÐµ)
[u'\xd0\xa2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x85\xd0\xbd\xd1\x96\xd0\xba\xd1\x83\xd0\xbc (\xd1\x83\xd1\x87\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8\xd1\x89\xd0\xb5)']
```

1. Why do variable print output differs from this variable in list?
2. How to get correct value from web-page

> Технікум (училище)

In interactive python it can be get from backslashed codes in this way

```
>>> print '\xd0\xa2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x85\xd0\xbd\xd1\x96\xd0\xba\xd1\x83\xd0\xbc (\xd1\x83\xd1\x87\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8\xd1\x89\xd0\xb5)'.decode('utf8')
Технікум (училище)
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup has used an incorrect codec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use encoding `latin1`

**Ex:**

```
import requests
import bs4

s = requests.get('http://vstup.info/2017/i2017i483.html')
tmp = s.text.replace("</td></tr></td></tr><tr><td>", "</td></tr><tr><td>")

bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(tmp, "html.parser")

content = bs.find("div", {"id": "okrArea"}).find("table", {"id": "about"}).findAll("tr")

typ = content[1].findAll("td")[1].get_text() #ZVO type

print typ.encode("latin1")
```

**Output:**

```
Технікум (училище)
```

Answer (score 3):

You made the mistake of trusting the HTTP content character set set by the server, by using `response.text`. This gives you Unicode text decoded from the binary response data using the header information, which here is wrong. You then give the Unicode string to BeautifulSoup, which assumes that it was correctly decoded.

Instead, use the `response.content` attribute, which gives you the raw binary string content body:

```
tmp = s.conent.replace("</td></tr></td></tr><tr><td>", "</td></tr><tr><td>")
```

Now the data remains a binary string and BeautifulSoup will do the decoding for you, based on information in the HTML document itself (there’s a `<meta>` tag with the correct codec information in there):

```
>>> import requests, bs4
>>> s = requests.get('http://vstup.info/2017/i2017i483.html')
>>> tmp = s.content.replace("</td></tr></td></tr><tr><td>", "</td></tr><tr><td>")
>>> bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(tmp, "html.parser")
>>> content = bs.select("div#okrArea table#about tr")
>>> typ = content[1].findAll("td")[1].get_text()
>>> print typ
Технікум (училище)
```

Comment: FWIW, the page is a little bit confusing. It has a `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` but the response header has `Encoding: ISO-8859-1`. Yes, I realise that's sadly all too common.

Comment: @PM2Ring ah, yes, I missed the `.text` error there. Corrected.